# Nodejs render Angular page with data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, url-routing

So I have a use case for my website. The User should be able to enter an URL with a parameter (the id of something) and gets back the Page with the corresponding information about the entry in the Database. I am using Angular4 and are not sure how to do this.

It is easy to do this when the user is already on the website with a simple request. How can I return a specific route/page in angular already filled with that data? I am not sure what I am looking for maybe someone can push me in the right direction.

**Edit:**

Ok maybe the Question was not clear enough.
I have a ruining angular4 Application done. Users can enter Information about themselves and share information. There is a use case where A path in nodejs (with an id parameter) should return a page with the information that the backend provided. I am not sure how to do that i feel like it should be relay easy but i am missing something.

Comment: you don't know how to display data from a database?

Comment: I do understand how to do it. If the user is on my page and enters the id its no problem to send everything back via json and handle the response. I am unsure about the response to a direct get request with URL parameters. Maybe i am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the URL.

```
 router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
     var userID = req.params.id;

     // search db for the data
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it... what i wanted but could not express was using an **Angular** not a nodejs route parameter:

```
{
    path: 'someroute/:id',
    component: someComponent
 },
```

And then doing a normal http request within the ngOnInit function. Maybe someone in the future will be as confused as me so i am leaving this on display.